# PostMessage between Iframe hierarchy

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to communicate between grandfather and grandson iframes.

In case of one level (parent - child), I can send:

Child => parent:
`window.parent.postMessage("message", "*");`

Parent => child:
`iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, "*");`

The problem is how to handle communication when the relations are grandfather and grandson.
I tried with `window.parent.parent` but it does not work.

I thought maybe to write some proxy code that will be added in the middle iframe and will pass the messages, but maybe there is another better solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding some proxy script.

And also added to each message "sender" key

```
<script>

    var father = 'aaa';
    var child = 'bbb';
    var proxyIframe;

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
        proxyIframe = document.getElementById('proxyIframe');
    });


    window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
        if (e.data) {
            if (e.data.sender === father) {
                proxyIframe.contentWindow && proxyIframe.contentWindow.postMessage(e.data, "*");
            } else if (e.data.sender === child) {
                window.parent.postMessage(e.data, "*");
            }
        }
    }, false);


</script>
```

Hope it can help anyone